# Token can be viewed from google developer tools

Tags: javascript, python, security, flask

To process a payment, I am doing the following:

In my html I have this script:

```
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        application_context: {
                brand_name: "Mybrandname",
                shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
            },
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '5.99'
          }
        }]
      });
    },

onApprove: function(data, actions) {

  var bleep = new Audio();
 bleep.setAttribute("src", "static/payment_success.mp3");
 bleep.currentTime=0;
 bleep.play();

      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        window.location.href = "{{ url_for ('payment_success', token=token ) }}";
        alert('Tu pago se ha procesado con éxito, ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '. Cierra esta ventana y se te redirigirá a tu perfil');
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>
```

.

The problem is that from developers tools in Chrome, I can see the token, instead o showing just 'token' it shows the actual token and the url. It shows something like:"payment_success/thetokenrevealed"  and now if someone enters the token url they can access my website without paying. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: you probably need your own account system.

Comment: Don't redirect on the client...

Comment: How could this be done instead? @Andreas